How to install HP LaserJet MFP130nw network printer?
Network printer used to work with hp-lip drivers (not the ones from Ubuntu repository, but from HP website: hplip-3.23.12-plugin.run and hplip-3.23.12.run), but you can only install USB, not the network printer. I don't know what I've didn't try by now, this is hell. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.
Anyone has the same trouble and found a solution?

[edit] your question to indicate which Linux distro/version you are using

You say you have tried lots of things but have not said what those things are so it's difficult to help. I installed my similar model HP printer a long time ago in network mode and have not had any issues. From memory all I did was use the printer screen/buttons to configure the printer on a static IP address with the correct gateway address. Then just added the printer in the Ubuntu settings menu by entering the static IP address which should find the printer.

Used to work with network printers, now it's just losing connection with them, and it started happening recently. Yes, I have a static IP address for printer, given by DHCP server.

I used the app hp-setup to install the drivers for my MFP283cdw connected to LAN. I had to manually enter the printer's IP address in the setup app for it to recognize the printer.

I had same issue - I'm on Ubuntu 24.04. I did this:
sudo apt install cups cups-client
hp-plugin -i
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install rc
sudo apt install 9base
sudo apt install ii
sudo apt install hplip hplip-data hplip-gui hplip-doc

and other stuff hp-setup demanded
but finally I went to the SEARCH APP MENU (lower left corner on desktop)
then simply typed hplip - it told me it couldn't see or detect printer
I simply unplugged POWER CABLE from printer and USB type B CABLE and re-plugged them.
Then it simply worked. It found my 1510 DeskJet HP printer... and can use it via hplip app.
Hope this helps.
